# How can I get music in other languages from the iTunes Store on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, music, itunes-store, language

So, I have English iTunes and I wanted to get a Spanish song. Is there a way I could change the iTunes store I am using to get it and then change it back or something?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in iTunes to choose `Latino` music.

See the picture below (I'm on iTunes 11).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Outside of what is available in the US iTunes store as noted in the other answer, it is not possible to switch stores unless you have a valid method of payment (credit card or gift card from that country) and billing address for that country. Even then, iTunes may try to make it difficult for you to do so because it will read your IP address and use that to try to determine where you are in the world. Once it realizes you are in the US, it may try to redirect you automatically to the US store.